# c# sending email operation timed out

Tags: c#, email

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("teunenrichard@gmail.com",        "ipadcraze@hotmail.com", "Movies this month", "Hello this is a test mail");
msg.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
NetworkCredential xre = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("teunenrichard@gmail.com", "Password");
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Credentials = xre;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.Send(msg);
```

This is the code i run in a form . load to do a test email but it will not rund and says operation timed out. ive tried everything please help
            `MessageBox.Show("mail sent");`

Comment: The port for gmail ssl is 465 and not 587. Try changing it.

Comment: @Ross ? I've always used 587.

Comment: sorry here is a copy of the error message

Comment: @john 587 for TLS 465 for SSL, according to the documentation? https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# Send email using visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50295545/c-sharp-send-email-using-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Timeout" property for your Smtp client . I think 0 is max

```
 smtp.Timeout = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

For better Understanding of the error message try putting your code in a Try-Catch Block and then see the inner exception of the catch in MessageBox.Show(). It might provide you some more information regarding the error and might help/guide you in the right direction to resolve it. Something like below:-

```
try
{
  //your email sending logic
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send your mails using background thread, so as to make sure that your UI thread does not block and returns immediately. You can do something like this

```
 private async void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var result = await SendMail();
            if (result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mail sent");
            }
        }

        private Task<bool> SendMail()
        {
            var task = Task.Run<bool>(() =>
            {
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("sendermail@gmail.com", "recievermail@gmail.com", "Movies this month", "Hello this is a test mail");
                msg.IsBodyHtml = false;

                using(SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    NetworkCredential xre = new NetworkCredential("sendermail@gmail.com", "Password");
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    smtp.Credentials = xre;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Send(msg);

                    return true;
                }

            });
            return task;
        }
```

Comment: ok i tried this code it runs succesfully but i do not receive any emails

Comment: You can try it again. I just changed "SendAsync" to "Send" and it works