# c# Send email using visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, email

I am trying to send an email using visual studio 2015 on a windows pc. i amusing a outlook email adress to send the emails please can somebody help me get the code rigth. i have tried many methods but they either timeout or say that they caanot send failure to send email. Please help

```
SmtpClient cv = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com", 25);
cv.EnableSsl = true;
cv.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxemail@mail.com", "password");
try
{
    cv.Send("xxxemail@mail.com", "xxxanotheremail@mail.com", "", "Hello");
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
catch(Exception w)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not send" + w.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question so we know what you've tried.

Comment: There are a few ways to do this - I guess it would be best if you pick one of your failed attempts and give some specifics about the error that you're getting.

Comment: this is my latest attempt

Comment: I'm pretty sure live.com requires a different port than the standard smtp port 25. Also I think it makes most people wince to read *"Send E-Mail using Visual Studio"*.

Comment: Do you know if there is possibly a firewall blocking the SMTP port?

Comment: not my actual email just a  newly random created one

Comment: where would i check my firewall settings? and i did change the port to 587 now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add smtp hotmail account to send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851319/how-to-add-smtp-hotmail-account-to-send-mail)

Answer (score 0):

you must figured out that setting the SmtpClient Credentials property before setting the `UseDefaultCredentials = false` causes the credentials to be ignored.

fails:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("richardteunen2@hotmail.com","pass");
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

Works:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("richardteunen2@hotmail.com","pass");
```

Comment: still not working. It just says that the operation timed out

Answer (score -1):

```
    public async Task<bool> SendAsync(EmailMessage message)
    {
        bool result = true;

        try
        {
            using (var email = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to@gmail.com", message.Subject, message.Body))
            {
                var mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password"), EnableSsl = true };

                await mailClient.SendMailAsync(email);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
Hotmail settings
Server          Port
smtp.live.com   25, 587
```